# How to test nested callbacks with Mocha/Sinon?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

What is the/one correct way to test this piece of JavaScript code using, e.g, Mocha/Sinon:

```
var App = function(endPoint, successCallback) {
    var channel = new WebSocket(endPoint);
    channel.onopen = function(ev) {
        successCallback();
    };
};
```

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
describe('App', function() {
    it('test should create instance and call success', function(done) {
        var app = new App('ws://foo.bar:123/', done);
        var stub = sinon.stub(app, 'channel');
        stub.yield('onopen');
    });
});
```

Apparently, that does not work as `channel` is not accessible from outside the constructor. How would you test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a factory for Websocket such as:

```
var myApp = {
    createWebsocket: function () {
        return new Websocket;
    }
};
```

This would make spying on the myApp.createWebsocket return value `channel` very easy:

```
sinon.spy(myApp, 'createWebsocket);
var channel = myApp.createWebsocket.firstCall.returnValue;
var stub = sinon.stub(channel, 'onopen');
stub.yield('onopen');

// Clean up
myApp.createWebsocket.restore();
```

Comment: I like your approach, even though it does require code changes

Comment: 'even though it does require changes'?